# Method chaining with variable variables

Tags: php, oop, rightnow-crm, oracle-service-cloud

The API that I'm using (ConnectPHP of Oracle Service Cloud) follows the chaining approach. For example:

```
$incident = new Incident();
$incident->CustomFields->c->make = "Same value";
$incident->StatusWithType->Status->ID = 34;
$incident->save();
```

How would I go about achieving the same if the subsequent properties of the `$incident` object are generated dynamically? For example:

```
$data = array();
$data[0]['parts'] = array('CustomFields', 'c', 'make');
$data[0]['value'] = "Some value";

$data[1]['parts'] = array('StatusWithType', 'Status', 'ID');
$data[1]['value'] = 34;

$incident = new Incident();
foreach($data as $array)
{
   foreach($array['parts'] as $key)
   {  
      // how will I generate 
      // (1) $incident->CustomFields->c->make = $array['value']
      // (2) $incident->StatusWithType->Status->ID = $array['value']
   }
}
$incident->save();
```

#### What I tried

```
$incident = new Incident();
foreach($data as $array)
{
   $parts = implode('->', $array['parts']);
   $incident->{$parts} = $array['value']; // this doesn't work even though $parts is coming out with the expected pattern because I think it is converting it into a string representation
}
$incident->save();
```

Comment: $incident->CustomFields->c->make and $incident->StatusWithType->Status->ID are static keys but you want to update those with dynamic values right??

Comment: The keys might change too...I just used 2 of the keys as an example. But the pairing will be fixed, i.e. `StatusWithType` will always be followed by `Status->ID`.

Comment: so  array('CustomFields', 'c', 'make') should be CustomFields->c->make........                 array('StatusWithType', 'Status', 'ID') should beStatusWithType->Status->ID..............  array('1', '2', '3')  =>  1->2->3 ......like this .............your expecting right??

Comment: Yes, you're right @kranthi

Comment: can you try this,                   foreach($data as $array)
{
  $va = implode('->',$array['parts']);
  $incident->$va = $array['value'];
}

Comment: Yeh, implode doesn't work. Already tried it.

Comment: please try this   foreach($data as $array)
{
  $incident->{$array['parts'][0]}->{$array['parts'][1]}->{$array['parts'][2]} = $array['value'];
}

Comment: above one working fine...i think???

Answer (score 1):

*If there is no risk of user input* , you can create string of all object keys and **use eval** like this

```
$incident = new stdClass();
foreach($data as $key=>$chain){
  $str = "{'".implode("'}->{'",$chain['parts'])."'}";
  eval("@\$incident->$str = '$chain[value]';");
}
print_r($incident);
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/923232

OUTPUT is as

```
stdClass Object
(
    [CustomFields] => stdClass Object
        (
            [c] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [make] => Some value
                )

        )

    [StatusWithType] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Status] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 34
                )

        )

)
```

and now you can easily access like `$incident->CustomFields->c->make`

@kranthi is technically right(*in the comment*), I given the implementation.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this does contain user input. So I would prefer not to use go this way. Upvoted anyways though. I've found the solution, will post in a bit for reference purpose.

Answer (score 0):

So, kranthi was on the right track.

```
$incident = new Incident();
foreach($data as $array)
{
   $this->setDynamicFields($incident, $array['parts'], $array['value']); 
}
$incident->save();

function setDynamicFields($obj, $parts, $value)
{
   if(is_array($parts) && count($parts) == 3)
   {
       $obj->{$parts[0]}->{$parts[1]}->{$parts[2]} = ($parts[0] == 'StatusWithType' ? (int) $value: $value);
   }
}
```

The trick was to pass the whole `$incident` object as a function argument (I think that's called as dependency injection if I'm not wrong) and using `->` as a literal instead of a string that resided inside a variable.

Comment: what if there is 2 or 4 element in array, like `array('CustomFields', 'c');` or `array('CustomFields', 'c', 'make','extra');` ?

Comment: @user2486 : checked this condition if(is_array($parts) && count($parts) == 3) ????

Comment: @kranthi : please share you answer